# How to cope with interest payed by banks?

Tags: practical-islam, riba, banking

People have saving accounts in bank to save money in a secure place. And Salary accounts are also a kind of Saving account. Banks usually pay a small amount of interest after particular interval. My question is:

Is it ok to let the money come to bank account then withdraw it and give it to poor people. Or even this is still haraam? If so, then how to cope with it?

Comment: In my country, there are some banks that don't give interest, but do business with your money, and give you your share of the income. I think that is ok, but I am not sure.

Comment: A lot of research has been done on this matter and still there's no perfect answer to it.

Comment: Ask for an interest-free account. That's what I do.

Comment: similar question but asking for khanafi view http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/intention-to-get-rid-of-riba-money

Comment: similar question that asks about using interest to pay interest of other people http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8122/is-it-ok-to-pay-interest-debt-with-interest-money

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no doubt that this interest is ribaa which is prohibited by Islam as a form of thulm (wrongdoing). So the question is, how do you deal with it? Who's money is it, anyway?

There are two opinions of the scholars on this (source: Islamic finance class, don't have AMJA  fatwa or anything like that on me):

- **Don't touch it:** It's interest. Just leave it in the bank, don't do anything with it.
- **Give it away as charity:** This falls under the category of "disposing of haram income." Some scholars say you are allowed to give it away as charity -- *but you cannot expect any reward for doing so.* It's not legitimate charity money. But at least you're disposing of it.

Allah knows best. I would personally ask for a non-interest account, switch banks to get a non-interest account, or keep a total in a spreadsheet somewhere to eventually dispose of.

Comment: I'd encourage disposing it as "donation" to open companies like wikipedia.

Comment: @Power-Inside this question is about fiqh, not personal recommendations. BTW, Wikipedia has a strong anti-Islam bias.

Comment: Indeed, otherwise I would have expanded my point and posted it as an answer. I was just laying out what other possibilities you can do to dispose the riba without actually benefiting from or "using" that riba.

Comment: Great answer, @ashes999. A couple of things: it's not that Wikipedia has an anti-Islam bias; it's just that Muslims haven't been active on it. Most articles on Islam too are lopsided with strong Shee'ah or Sufi leanings (no offence to anyone). Read their policies carefully and you will see what I mean. About the donation thingy, I asked a scholar about this and he said that the interest money donation should be done to non-Muslims only.

Comment: @Najeeb I've seen edit wars over this. It does have a fairly strong bias, at least as far as the few who really control Wikipedia. No worries though.

Comment: Some people argue that haraam income should not be used for Islamic charities or given to Muslims. If that's the case, sending it to Wikipedia would be perfect :)

Comment: @Muz I don't believe I've heard that opinion before.

Answer (score 3):

**Riba** is **Haram**.

Here, in my country, they offer online banking. I think this happens all over the world. So, I can create as much as accounts online. Then I have created a separate account for **Riba** and each month I transfer the interest to that virtual account via online banking. So, **Riba** doesn't mix up with my money and I don't need to care about that **Riba**. But I am not sure about giving it to a charity.

Another way is, talking to the bank not to give you interest. Some banks accepts this, some will say they will transfer it to another account automatically each month. Some says 'No'!.

Please note this also: Banks usually charge an amount for each ATM withdrawals you do. Some people account that withdrawal fee with this **Riba**. It's is a service charge from the bank and you can't pay that service charge using **Riba**.

Simply, **do not use Riba, its haram**

Answer (score 2):

there are some kinds of accounts without interest but other benefits. if you could not find them. you can save your money in other way. for example buy stock of some company or gold or a land.

some scholars say if you do not want to receive any interest and Bank itself pay you then there is no problem.

anyway Islam wants to Muslims use their extra money for donation or lending to who need or partnership with other Muslims for doing business and sharing the Benefit or loss.

its better to not save your money in Bank or find a real Islamic Bank.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that you are supposed to avoid interest as much as possible. Speaking from a United States perspective, there are plenty of checking accounts without interest. There are mutual funds that avoid financial stocks. There are halal home buying companies that let you buy a house without dealing with interest-based loans. And if you can't afford those, then there's nothing wrong with living in an apartment.

If you can't avoid it (for example, your landlord here in my state is required to give you interest on your security deposit), then you donate the exact amount when you get the money back.

Answer (score -1):

Its riba ,its haram, please cut any kind of relationship with it, shut off the concept giving charity with it, only one safest possible solution is expend this money for feeding those animal which are haram to us,
Also cut off the relationship with those people who are enjoying it