# what should be done with bank account interests to avoid riba?

Tags: fiqh, riba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to cope with interest payed by banks?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/159/how-to-cope-with-interest-payed-by-banks)

If you have an account in a bank that automatically puts an interest rate on it , 
how can someone in this case avoid being in Riba ?
Is giving it as Sadaqa allowed ?