# Intention to get rid of Riba money?

Tags: sunni, riba, money, hanafi

I have some Riba money in my account.  With what intention do I get rid of this money from the list below?

```
Lillah
Sadaqah
Zakat
Sadaqah Wajibah
Fidya (Kaffarah)
```

I have been presented with these options on an islamic donation site, and don't know which option to chose to donate Riba money.

Hanafi view please.

Comment: similar question generally for islam is here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/159/how-to-cope-with-interest-payed-by-banks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even among the scholars who support purification of interest-based income there are strong arguments *against* disposing of the money toward such things as maintenance of masjid or in the cause of God: God is pure and loves pure things, so spending impure funds directly in His cause is hardly appropriate.

As such, the first four options would be discouraged.  Although one could research to learn exactly where the money is going (*Zakat* and *sadaqah*, for example, may end up being paid either to the poor and needy (acceptable) or *fee sabilillah* (discouraged)), it would be better to categorize it as *fidyah*.  *Fidyah*, being the expiation for not fasting, is by its nature spent only on feeding the poor.

You should not, of course, consider this payment as discharging any *actual* obligations for *zakat* or *fidyah* you may have.  You are disposing of these funds with the intent of getting rid of them, not with the intent of receiving any sort of benefit and/or reward therefrom.

Answer (score 0):

None of the options from:
Lillah
Sadaqah
Zakat
Sadaqah Wajibah
Fidya (Kaffarah)

Riba is interest money, which is not usually a donation.
There are not many options in North America from what I can tell.
Unless you're in South East Asia, it's much easier - since you will need to confirm with the person if they accept that money. 
Some info here: http://qa.sunnipath.com/issue_view.asp?HD=1&ID=364&CATE=43 and 
http://islamqa.info/en/ref/2370

Answer (score -1):

Allah is pure and only accept pure things. Even the people at Prophets Muhammad's (PBUH) time, before his proclaimation of prophethood, knew that. They left the reconstruction of Kaaba incomplete due to lack of availability of "pure" funds.

I think your intention should be to get rid of the riba money. Doesn't matter where you spend it, you should not expect any reward for it.

Comment: This doesn't really help.  I am on a website which has given me the above options to donate money.  Which option do I chose for donating Riba money.  I know that Riba money is not to be given as zakat money.

Comment: The reason for zakat not being acceptable as you are trying to fulfill a "farz" with something that was not yours to begin with. Since others are not, you can give it under any heading.