# What to do with the Riba (interest) money?

Tags: fiqh, riba, hanafi, sadaqah

I have some interest money in my account and I recently came to know it is haram. I want to get rid of it.  Please tell me the ways to spend it.

Can I spend it as wedding or birthday gift to my relatives? Can I give it to my mother or sister?

I ask for Hanafi school answer.

Comment: I would rather donate it for a good cause, spending it towards gift will account as personal usage rather than actually getting rid of it, but that is simply my opinion may Allah guide you to the right path.

Comment: See also: "[How to cope with interest payed by banks?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/159/9123)"

Answer (score 4):

As far as I studied some well-established reference, and discussed with some scholars (yes, they are hanafi),  (i'll update my answer asap i get hold onto related on-line reference)

if you have no other feasible/safe way to store your money in a interest-based bank,

1. you should take out the "riba" amount asap, to separate it from your halal money,
2. use it somewhere "dirty" (but needed) public spend, e.g. construction of masjid toilet, purchase toilet-consumables (such as toilet-papers, cleaning items etc.), or donate to a absolutely poor person.
3. But, you have to make sure that you are doing it WITHOUT any intention of earning "good deed" (neki) or reward from ALLAH ta'ala. You are just dispensing the money.

Again, this is the least way out. 
The most beneficial way to store your money is not the bank, rather make it useful for your here-after.

and ALLAH ta'ala knows the best, and may forgive me for my ignorance.

Comment: so finally it means, that the questioner cannot use it to buy a gift or donate it to the near kin? ryt?

Comment: Here ([IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/81952)) is a perfect reference which explains in detail what you've written briefly. It says, that if one's brother / sister is in dire need of money, then yes, they can help him / her with the interest money, not in the form of Zakat or Sadaqa, but *just like that.*

Comment: @azam jajhakaLLAH brother.