# Utilization of profit on saving account

Tags: riba

I have saving account in a bank. I obtained profit of Rs. 12500/-. It is interest? How can i get rid of this amount? Can i give it to my brother who is needy right now?
Thanks and regards

Comment: Yes, it is classified as 'interest'.

Comment: Also plz refer: http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/212/3259