# Is profit from bank on your money is halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, money, halal-certification

As we saved our money in bank e.g( national-saving bank) for a period of 4 to 5 years and we get profit on that money according to our savings. Is that profit on our money is halal or haram as because no matter of serving for that money done by us? 
If anyone guide properly please

Comment: If money is through interest, then it is haraam. See: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/159/how-to-cope-with-interest-payed-by-banks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually profit given by bank is riba (interest) and riba is haram.